# django - filtering on model default representation

Tags: python, django

Django/Python newbie here.

Let's use the example table from the django book on this page: http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter10/

```
class Author(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    email = models.EmailField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
```

Here is an example filter statement used to access the Author table:

```
a = Author.objects.get(first_name='Adrian', last_name='Holovaty')
```

What if I don't have the first and last name in separate variables? What if I only have the entire name together? I'd like to do something like this:

```
aName = 'Adrian Holovaty'
a = Author.objects.get(Author.self=aName)
```

I'm looking to access that object representation "property" somehow. Sure I could split aName on the space and do the lookup as above. But what if it isn't so clear how to split the whole name? Suppose I was trying to split something like "New York Knicks" or "Rip Van Winkle"? In the first example the first_name would be "New York", and in the second it would be just "Rip".

Comment: So... which question are you asking?

Comment: I'd like to access the __unicode__(self) "property" inside a filter or get on the table.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you cannot do that is that `__unicode__` is evaluated in Python, **using** the data selected by the queryset's SQL.

So there is no way that the database can predict the value generated by the Python method `__unicode__`.

That said, there are many ways:

1. if you rely on [django-haystack](http://haystacksearch.org/) for search, then you can put `{{ object }}` which is the result of `object.__unicode__` in the template of the model class. Then, you can enable search by `__unicode__` output.
2. add a cached_unicode CharField to the model, use a [pre_save signal receiver](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#pre-save) (override the [save() method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods)) to update self.cached_unicode, then you can filter(cached_unicode='Foo Bar')
3. use [SQL CONTACT](http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sql-concatenate.html)(author.first_name, ' ', author.last_name) = 'Foo Bar' either with [Author.objects.raw()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#performing-raw-queries) either with [author_queryset.extra()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#extra)

Comment: Sigh. There has to be an easier way. I'd *really* like to be able to do "a = Author.objects.get(first_name+last_name='Adrian Holovaty')" but that gets a "keyword" error.

Comment: How many `Authors` are you dealing with? You could split the query string on spaces and perform multiple lookups for each of the possible last names. For those `Authors` that match, check if the `__unicode__` representation matches the full query name. It's not as good as a single database lookup but for your purposes it may be good and fast enough.

Comment: I thought you were asking for a generic way... So I added two solutions which work if you know how __unicode__ builds in advance (ie. you know that it's a concatenation of first name space last name). thank you for your feedback!

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `getbyname` method to your class which splits the name and peforms the query. Job done.

Comment: But how do you split the name if you don't know *where* to split the name? Also, am having trouble trying to track down "getbyname".

Comment: @Cromulent You won't find it until you write it. As to the splitting, that is for you to design.